# DialogFlow integration with Twilio Text Messaging

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to follow some tutorials to use dialog flow with twilio text messaging.

But when I click on Integrations menu, doesn't appear the option Twilio Text Messaging, there is only a link to documentation (on Open Source Section).

I need to enable something in my account? Why this option doesn't appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of Twilio integration was moved to open source in July 2020. ([Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/release-notes#January_06_2020)). Hence, it  doesn't have an enable-disable option in the Dialogflow console.

To use Twilio you need to follow the instructions in the GitHub repository which is provided in the Dialogflow Integration console for Twilio (open source) ie. to integrate open source integrations with your Dialogflow Agent (in this case Twilio Text Messaging) use [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations#dialogflow-integration) integration setup followed by Twilio [integration](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/twilio#twilio-text-messaging-integration) setup.